# If Human birth is so Auspicious and Rare, why does God let some people be born as - Lunatic, Autistic, Schizophrenic et cetera?

Tags: karma, moksha, sin

> **मानुष्यं च समासाद्य स्वर्गमोक्षप्रसाधनम्।**
>   **नाचरत्यात्मनः श्रेयः स मृतः शोचते चिरम्॥३०॥**
>
> The human body is the means for achieving of the heaven and moksa and even after achieving the same, he does not do good to himself. After death he keeps on thinking for a long time.
>     
>   **देवासुराणां सर्वेषां मानुष्यं चातिदुर्लभम्।**
>   **तत्सम्प्राप्य तथा कुर्यान्न गच्छेन्नरकं यथा॥३१॥**
>
> It is difficult for even the gods and the demons to achieve the human body. Therefore after achieving the human body, one should act in a way that he has not to face the agonies of the hell. 
>     
>   The above verses are from [TheDestroyer's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18430/why-does-uma-samhita-chapter-24-of-shiva-purana-insult-women).

And we all along find several verses through Hinduism saying this- **Human Birth is extremely rare and auspicious. We must not waste it and effect our Moksha practicing Yoga *(Karma, Gyaana, Bhakti, Kriya, Raaja Yog: means of attaining Brahma)*.**
  
Now, God knows this very well. Then how can it *(from 'it' I mean genderless Brahma)* make some people **Lunatic, Autistic, Schizophrenic** et cetera.
There is no method of their Moksha(the highest duty of their Human Birth), until unless God itself comes to give them moksha, or Some Real Guru comes and enlightens them.

Then, **Why God produces them like that, where it is certain they are never going to achieve no goals?**

If it be argued- **'*God gave those human being punishment of previous Karma*'** , then also God could have given them inferior births such as- fishes, birds, animals, et cetera. Why does God give them Human Birth?

**Why does God need to deliberately make them Human Beings, and then deliberately defy this law- *'Human Birth is rare and meant to attain moksha.'* .**

**Why does God need to create this 'divine holy body'(meant for Moksha) just to see it 'wasting'*(as a lunatic person can never use his Human form for Moksha)*?**

Comment: Good argument, so it appears human birth isn't special.

Comment: @sv. Every creature is special. It is just that only human is capable to attain divinity.

Comment: Manas & Matters are interconnected. Whatever is in manas has to manifest materially. If after death of a Jeeva, it's manas fulfils the requirement of being human, it is manifested as human. ( Takes human womb).

Comment: @sv. Yes. In my opinion, these concepts of *'Human Birth being superior'* wad just an idea to make people proud of their birth and thus do good to society.(in name of acquiring good Karma or moksha).

Comment: @Aghori if the Manas effects Human Birth, then did those who are born as Lunatic think of being Mentally disordered?

Comment: @AnuragSingh That's what I think too. Handicap people (with physical or mental problems) were considered worthless births, demons etc. and looked down upon ("it validates the Karma theory") instead of showing compassion and taking care of them.

Comment: @sv. They were considered worthless by deluded people. Not by scriptures.

Comment: @TheDestroyer "Not by scriptures." - see [one of the answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18800/2995) below: "In several Agama & Tantra texts its clearly stated that a person who has bodily deformity, has one finger more in hand or less, is not fit to be a Guru." - if you need the exact scriptural reference, maybe you can comment under that answer.

Comment: @sv. Ok. He is  not fit for Guru but he can get Moksha, ultimate Goal. Still his human birth is useful.

Comment: @sv. I also don't believe such sayings of scriptures, even if they are DharmaShastras. But we can't ignore 90 good teachings of scriptures just because they have 10 bad teachings.

Comment: @Aghori '90 good teachings of scriptures ... 10 bad teachings' - this is the reason I asked the question on [morality](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18744). As you can see from answers there is heavy reliance on scriptures. A lot of people blindly follow what it says in scriptures and don't apply critical thinking.

Comment: @Aghori  This is what Vivekananda said in [this](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Epistles_-_Second_Series/CXXIV_Sir) letter: "The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class and malice. Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love are acceptable, **the rest are to be rejected.**" So in this case, I would reject the statement such as "a person who has bodily deformity, has one finger more in hand or less, is not fit to be a Guru."

Comment: I too reject such verses without any delay. @sv. But in most of the cases, such verses are either interpolations only. Original scriptures are full of divinity, love & harmony. And I hope you know about **Ashtavakra** the great. He was enlightened. Handicapping has nothing to do with liberation. :)

Comment: @Aghori Yes, keep rejecting and we'll be left with a morality that doesn't need scriptures to begin with :P

Comment: @sv, *"The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors"* - oh, and the person who said above statement had no fallacies ? maybe his statement above itself is a fallacy. do you just decide to believe whatever 'feels right' at the present moment. You are quoting Vivekananda to support your opinion ? The same person said "if you do not harm any living being for 12 years, lions and tigers will be calm before you", and you ridiculed that. So.. yeah, don't quote others as authority when you're actually going by your own intellect.

Comment: @sv, btw, i have read almost entire 'Complete works of Swami Vivekananda', and 'Ramakrishna Kathamrita' start to finish. I have great respect for his tapas, but not even close to the saints who wrote the puranas.

Comment: @ram Sringeri Jagadguru once decimated a statement made by an inquirer that Sankaracharya and Vivekananda were comparable. He conceded that Vivekananda worked for the upliftment of Hindu dharma but categorically stated that he is no comparison with Sankara.

Comment: I don't see your point. **Only** humans can attain moksha, but that does not mean **all** humans can attain moksha.

Answer (score 6):

We all live in Mrityu Lok or Karma Lok. It is called karma lok because we do Karma in this world/lok and get karma phal in return. Whatever deeds we do, we will surely get Karma phal of that deed in return.

The grief or joy we experience in life is nothing but result of our karma referred as karma phal. If we do good deeds then we will get joy and if we do bad then we will get grief.

As per **Bhagwat Geeta** and **Garur Puran**, when human dies then he only carries his karma phal (not worldly things like money, fame etc) with him while traveling to other lok known as Yam lok. There Yamraj judges our all karma and decides whether we will stay in Hell or we will go to heaven.

Whether we will go to hell or heaven, The main purpose of visiting those loks are just to get karma phal of those karma which we did when we were alive in karma lok.

Even when we visit hell or heaven to get karma phal, our all karma phal can't be given in one lok at a time. Means, we have to take birth again to get all of our karma phal but that birth is not easy to get.

We only get birth in karma lok if any of our karma phal is pending, hence we have to take birth to get our pending karma phal. And that pending karma phal can be of any kind of karma whether it was sin karma or saintly karma.

**How Lord decide where and how we will be born**

Following things are decided for us before giving us birth

- whether we will born in rich family or in poor family.
- We will born as beautiful/pretty person Or ugly person
- We will born as healthy or with diseased (mentally or physically).
- how long we will live or what will be our age.
- How much joy and how much grief we will get during our life time.
- How much struggle we need to do in our life to get success.
  and so on...

All these things are decided by the Lord himself before giving us birth. And these things are decided by our karma phal, those karma phal which we earn in our previous birth.

So whether people are **Lunatic**, **Autistic** or **Schizophrenic**... etc. It's not Lords wish to make such kind of people but It's karma phal of those people which they earn in previous birth and because of their karma phal they get diseases and other things, Lord can't do anything in this. Pretty much this is the only reason for getting birth in this lok so that we can get all of our karma phal because as par **Bhagawad Geeta** one can't get moksha, if their karma phal is pending. So to get moksha we have to get birth.

But unfortunate thing is that, when we get birth to get our pending karma phal then we also do new karma and hence our new karma phal gets generated and to get karma phal of our new karma (which we do in our current birth) we have to take birth again then in next birth while getting our pending karma phal we again do new karma and to get karma phal of new karma we again take birth and then again and again... This cycle of rebirth continues to flow because our karma continues to flow. As long as we are doing karma in this lok, we will be getting birth again and again and we will never get moksha.

Comment: so who gets Moksha then? coz we can not stop doing Karma ..right?

Comment: @just_do_it Yes, we can't stop doing karma as long as we alive. But there is a way in which we can get rid or our all karma phal. We can do our karma in such way so that our karma phal of that karma don't even generate. Yes, we can stop generation of karma phal of our karma. You can do any karma and you won't get karma phal of your karma. Read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/giving-alms-donation-charity-with-the-intention-of-getting-merit-will-give-me/20792#20792) to know, how to make our karma free of karma phal. And ask if any doubt left after reading.

Comment: @just_do_it Since you have asked about moksha then there is one more way of getting moksha. Read this to know another way of getting moksha.  [Do grave sinners attain moksha if they remember Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/do-grave-sinners-attain-moksha-if-they-remember-lord-vishnu)

Answer (score 6):

Well, we do bad karmas & we face the consequences, we do good karmas & we reap the benefits. So, why are you bringing in God into all this?

The diseases from which we suffer in our lifetime are nothing but signs of our bad karmas or crimes done in our previous lives. This has been explicitly stated in many scriptures.

Suppose, one does bad karmas in one's lifetime. Then he has two options: either to repent for it by performing the prescribed expiation measures or suffer the torments in the hellish planets.

After that (the punishments in hell), depending on the seriousness and nature of crimes, one gets birth in lower yonis like plants, insects, animals etc or gets human birth with bodily deformities (like deaf and dumb, blind etc) and diseases of various sorts.

> 11.52. **Thus in consequence of a remnant of (the guilt of former) crimes, are born idiots, dumb, blind, deaf, and deformed men,** who are
>   (all) despised by the virtuous
>
> 11.53. Penances, therefore, must always be performed for the sake of purification, **because those whose sins have not been expiated, are
>   born (again) with disgraceful marks.**
>
> **Manu Smriti.**

Depending on the nature of sins one gets one or the other diseases in their next births.

> **A person, stealing tin, is born suffering from eye diseases**. Fasting
>   for a day, he should give away one hundred Palas of tin. (6)
>
> **A person, pilfering lead, is born as suffering from head-diseases**.
>   Fasting for a day, he should give away one Dhenu weight of clarified
>   butter according to the proper regulations. (7)
>
> **A person, stealing milk, is born as a diabetic patient.** He should duly
>   give, unto a Brahmana, milk one Dhenu in weight. (8)
>
> **By stealing milk curd a person is born insane**. For purification, curd,
>   one Dhcnu in weight, should be given by him unto a Vipra. (9)
>
> **Satatapa Smriti, Chapter 5.**

So, all the diseases we suffer from in our present life are nothing but results of our own bad karmas which we did in our previous lives. And, we should not blame God  for that.

In several Agama & Tantra texts its clearly stated that a person who has bodily deformity , has one finger more in hand or less, is not fit to be a Guru. Because Guru himself has to be sinless but all these bodily deformities are nothing but pathakas (or sins) that he is carrying forward from his previous births.

Comment: I am saying, if a person does extremely grave sins, then he should be born by God as a lower yoni. That person could be born as a stray dog, and bear the bad Karma. Why should that sinner person, be born as a Human(the divine body for Moksha)? Over this, a deformed person still can effect his Moksha, but a person whose mind does not at all work(lunatic, Autistic et cetera) can never attain moksha. Why does God need to create this divine holy body(meant for Moksha) just to see it wasting(*as a lunatic person can never use his Human form for Moksha*)?

Comment: @AnuragSingh, people who do grave sins do get body of lower animals. people who do grave sins and also great punyas, get mix of both yonis - born as human, but with qualities of a pig, or with some handicap. The system is perfect. Human body is most suited for moksha. Doesn't mean other species are prohibited e.g. Jatayu (bird), Vali (monkey), Putana (Rakshasi).

Comment: @ram Yes. And their great punyas were only able to provide them a Human body to enjoy the fruits of great sins. What use are those 'great punyas' if being mentally disturbed, the person in Human Body is not able to enjoy those 'Great Punyas'.

Comment: @ram even if it is Karma fruit, then also it is truly a waste of divine Human body. Above all, if a Human being knowingly rates his Human Birth, he is accused for doing it. But what to do when this waste of Human body is done by God Itself(by making them Lunatic)?

Comment: @AnuragSingh, if you are a Chief Minister, and you are convicted in some corruption case, they put you in a 'A' class jail, with bed and fan. You might argue, what is the point of bed and fan when it is a jail anyways. But if you put him in a regular jail with common criminals, the VM would argue why police did NOT put him in 'A' class jail. Same way, if the balance of your papa-punya is such that you deserve a human body even though it is handicapped, then that's what you'll get. Once that punishment (and life) is over, you might get another human birth without any disability.

Comment: @ram Then what is ppoint in calling this- "**Human body is the divine most, and rarest even to God and Asuras.**" This "divine" body is to be got only to bear fruits. And in what ways is this divine and rarest Human body going to be divine for a person who has handicap, especially "Mental Handicap", where he cannot even think- 'Moksha of soul from this body also exists'

Comment: @AnuragSingh, Can ANY plant/animal/asura/deva attain moksha ? No (with very rare exceptions). Can ALL humans attain moksha? No. Can SOME human attain moksha ? Yes. That is why human birth is most divine AMONGST all the other yonis. Doesn't mean all human births are divine. Human birth is NECESSARY, but not SUFFICIENT for moksha.

Comment: @ram So clear my doubts thus- if a Human Being even after getting a Human birth does not utilize it for Moksha, and least for good deeds, then only that human is adjudged as a foolish person, not the God. But that Human Being who is mentally disabled, can neither utilize his birth for even good work. So who should be condemned for it- God or the Human Being.

Comment: I am saying, if a person does extremely grave sins, then he should be born by God as a lower yoni ---- NO it may not be like that. Most grave sinners get animal yonis. Those who have done relatively less amount of sins may get human bodies but there will be ailments, bodily deformities etc.. So the ailments are nothing but signs of purvajanma pathakas .@AnuragSingh

Comment: @AnuragSingh, there are lot of humans who don't have any bodily defects, but are very materialistic and never even think about doing good work, let alone God, because of their past karma and vasanas. So, they are are no different from autistic people, because both are incapable of thinking of moksha because of previous karma. Do you fault God for giving such people human birth also? you can keep on faulting God for all our mistakes then.

Answer (score 5):

Human birth is result of accumulation in Manas of a Jeeva. After death, the impressions on Manas if are in resonance with human birth, the Jeeva will appear in human womb. From Chapter 1 of Shiv Rahasya, we find.

> 62. Verily  from  lack of Awareness, there arises  Self-forgetfulness. From  that springs wrong knowledge.  From  wrong knowledge  comes greed, lust, envy,  hatred and other defects  of the mind. **Moreover, man reaps the fruits  of his  own  actions. And actions are done according  to his knowledge.**  Therefore, the performance of actions  that spring  from  wrong knowledge is  the greatest defect of all.
> 63. It is due to this cause that  men  are invested  with different kinds of physical bodies  and minds. For, **one is born with a body  and mind that  correspond to  the inner latent tendencies one has developed in a previous existence.  All bodies are born of mind. And the mind is nothing  but the light of the Soul tinted by  latent  tendencies  acquired in the past.** Therefore, know that whatsoever corporeal form a Soul assumes in this  life or the next, the same will  reflect his  mental state, even as the light that passes through a coloured gem (assumes that very colour).

This has been explained by Swāmi Vivekānanda (The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 2/Jnana-Yoga/The Cosmos: The Microcosm) very well [here](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_2/Jnana-Yoga/The_Cosmos:_The_Microcosm) as well.

> ...Again, if in the bioplasmic cell the infinite amount of impressions
>   from all time has entered, where and how is it? This is a most
>   impossible position, and until these physiologists can prove how and
>   where those impressions live in that cell, and what they mean by a
>   mental impression sleeping in the physical cell, their position cannot
>   be taken for granted. **So far it is clear then, that this impression is
>   in the mind, that the mind comes to take its birth and rebirth,
>   and uses the material which is most proper for it, and that the mind
>   which has made itself fit for only a particular kind of body will have
>   to wait until it gets that material.** This we understand. The theory
>   then comes to this, that there is hereditary transmission so far as
>   furnishing the material to the soul is concerned. But the soul
>   migrates and manufactures body after body, and each thought we think,
>   and each deed we do, is stored in it in fine forms, ready to spring up
>   again and take a new shape.When I look at you a wave rises in my mind.
>   It dives down, as it were, and becomes finer and finer, but it does
>   not die. It is ready to start up again as a wave in the shape of
>   memory. So all these impressions are in my mind, and when I die the
>   resultant force of them will be upon me. A ball is here, and each one
>   of us takes a mallet in his hands and strikes the ball from all sides;
>   the ball goes from point to point in the room, and when it reaches the
>   door it flies out. What does it carry out with it? The resultant of
>   all these blows. That will give it its direction. **So, what directs the
>   soul when the body dies? The resultant, the sum total of all the works
>   it has done, of the thoughts it has thought. If the resultant is such
>   that it has to manufacture a new body for further experience, it will
>   go to those parents who are ready to supply it with suitable material
>   for that body. Thus, from body to body it will go, sometimes to a
>   heaven, and back again to earth, becoming man, or some lower animal.
>   This way it will go on until it has finished its experience, and
>   completed the circle.** It then knows its own nature, knows what it is,
>   and ignorance vanishes, its powers become manifest, it becomes
>   perfect; no more is there any necessity for the soul to work through
>   physical bodies, nor is there any necessity for it to work through
>   finer, or mental bodies. It shines in its own light, and is free, no
>   more to be born, no more to die...

Therefore, Resultant forces of impressions decide next birth. For example, let's say you have gathered -

- 10 units of impressions of Dog.
- 15 units of impressions of Cockroache.
- 50 units of impressions of human.

Resultant impressions = max(10 of human, 15 of Cockroaches, 50 of human) = 50 units.

Therefore, you will get human birth after death with some hidden qualities of Cockroaches & dog.

Comment: How do you explain babies or mothers dying in the birthing process? Babies born with brain cancer, holes in their hearts who don't survive even a few years after their birth? What impressions are they holding? Dog, cockroach? "from body to body it will go" - before there were ever Humans walking on earth, there were cockroaches (300 million years ago), whose souls were those cockroaches harboring if there were no humans taking birth or dying?

Comment: I've answers. Let's continue on chat.

Comment: @sv, karma papa & punya explains everything. you sow what you reap.. performed an abortion in this birth ? you'll likely meet the same fate in one of your next births. break someone's leg without cause ? you'll likely be born handicapped in a future janma,

Comment: @sv "before humans walked on earth" - that is modern evolution theory. nobody is denying facts of dna resemblance, or fossil fules. but the inference derived from these facts (of a "physical" chain of births from amoeba to man) is not a fact, hence is up for debate. another inference can be derived - that soul 'graduates' or 'demotes' between bodies based on karma, and that is our philosophy - the same soul graduates from amoeba to human over millions of births. There are 84 lakh such yonis or bodies

Answer (score 1):

Everything and everyone is Brahman. When you harm others you are harming yourself. There are people in this world who bring great pains to animal and human life, ie they destroy themselves according to karmic laws.

just like an alcoholic do not understand at the time that he is destroying his liver, the evil doer does not understand what part of himself he is destroying.

But the sinner is still not one with Brahman. His field of experience is what he calls as himself. So when such an individual dies and when his mind is destroyed he comes into contact with reality, which includes the person he wronged or tortured. He comes into contact with the agony he created and that becomes his reality and he is born with this reality.

Asking why is there suffering in the world, when humans, animals and even the earth is tortured, ignored and humiliated, is like stabbing yourself in the leg and wondering 'why am I in pain?!'

When people do good deeds their soul becomes strong and the grace of God is on them. Painful realities they encounter while they die are not strong enough to change their reality because they gave comfort, trust and justice to souls their reality becomes enriched by their good actions and they receive appropriate life's, bodies and circumstances, when they are reborn.

But still everyone who are involved in the circle of Karma are all fools according to the great sages like Vyasa. Because you are still bound by Karma. liberation from the bondage of Karma is what you should seek. Which is easy in Kali Yuga(current yuga is kali. Kali the demonic era, not to be confused with Kahli the goddess). In Kali yuga you don't have to meditate for years or do great yagnas to attain liberation, simply chanting the name of God with submission, trust and honesty will do. If you don't do this you are carrying the burden of karma on your shoulders good or bad and therefore you are not free and hence will be born again and again to pay your karmic debt or receive credit or both, with increased levels of debt and low level of credit or vice versa.

God has nothing to do with it. God is Satchitananda. You can't know the wishes of Brahm because you are it and you choose to be ignorant of your reality in the spirit of playing the game of life. Whether you are suffering or having a good time you are always playing. There is no victim in life you are doing everything to yourself. Waking up to this reality is enlightenment.

Comment: I do agree with you. But tell- What if God/Brahma et cetera are just concepts created by intelligent people of the earlier times, only to control human beings to do good things(in fear of God and papa/punya). Human imagination and intelligence has no boundary. It can easily create a very beautiful concept, which looks as if completely real. What if all this is mere concept, no brahma actually exists?

Comment: That could be the case. The stupid person will never know the plans of the genius. There are a million ways to deceive the human mind it seems.Nonetheless, this philosophy is fascinating to me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. But I am striving to know, I believe intuitively that there is a God and I find the philosophy of Hinduism profound. 'If you cannot know God here and now that is the greatest loss' says our wise sages and I believe them because they are indeed wise. Your fear of being wasted comes from distrust in God who is the universe. He gave birth to you as your parents, cared for you as the sun, oceans and soil and will destroy you in time. If you submit your life to God as a sacrifice(yajna) then why be fearful? If you are doing trade with God then maybe he is true! who knows