# Every decision is the decision of the soul before birth?

Tags: atma, birth

Is it correct to say that it is the soul that takes the decision as to:

- where to be born?
- when to be born?
- which body to select?
- for how long to stay?
- what exactly it needs to learn in that birth?

Reason am asking this is because we all sometimes have this feeling when we are going through some stressful phase in our life as to why me? what wrong have I done? Am I not a good human?

Hope I'm making sense?

Comment: It's decision of Parbrahma, not of soul. If it's decision of soul then every soul would have chosed beautiful body to be born in rich family and there would have no any ugly or poor people left.

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18786/if-human-birth-is-so-auspicious-and-rare-why-does-god-let-some-people-be-born-a/18796#18796) might help you.

Comment: well I think soul decides itself coz it's the soul that seeks moksha but in order to reach that point it has to undergo many births and in each birth it has to gain some experiences that pushes it one level up closer to that ultimate motive.

Comment: You previous birth's karma decides all, not soul. Karma generates your karma phal and Lord applies that karma phal on next birth of your. If soul can decide everything then why he even choose to take birth? Why don't he choose to not take birth. When soul has to go from many yonies? Why soul don't decide to take moksha instead of birth. Why some people are born on so much poor family and some born with desease since soul decides everything. If soul decides everything then why some soul decided to take birth as handicap, or with mental illness.